# Using Ajax requests in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I want to build an app using Ajax. Whenever a user visits an other user page he can add him as a friend by clicking add friend link. This is my current code in users/show page

```
<% if current_user.friend?(current_user,@user) %>
  <%= link_to "Unfriend", relation_path(@relation), user: @user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure? This action cannot be undone' }, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% elsif @user != current_user %>
  <%= link_to "Add Friend", friendships_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :post, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

My code in relations controller

```
def create
  if params[:friend_id]
    if Relation.where(user_id: current_user.id, friend_id: params[:friend_id]).present?
      redirect_to user_path(params[:friend_id]), notice: "Already friends"
    elsif current_user.id == params[:friend_id]
      redirect_to user_path(params[:friend_id]), alert: "Invalid Request"
    else
      @relation = current_user.relations.new(friend_id: params[:friend_id], subject: Constants::Subject::MAKE)
      if @relation.save
        friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
        friend.relations.create!(friend_id: current_user.id, subject: Constants::Subject::MAKE)
        redirect_to user_path(params[:friend_id]), notice: "Added as friend"
      else
        redirect_to user_path(params[:friend_id]), alert: "Could not add as friend"
      end
    end
  else
    redirect_to current_user, notice: "Invalid Request"
  end
end
```

I am following [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) Ryan Bates rails casts. How can I make the link_to add friend Ajax request instead of html request. The current code is working fine. I want to add Ajax functionality for this. I have seen a lot of questions but I could not understand what exactly to be done. Please help.

Comment: Looks like _write code for me_. Show please what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Add remote: true to the link_to tag. There is more information in the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to) abou rails and ajax. You will need a respond_to block to handle the response.

Start with adding remote: true and use the console to see the call being made and what the response is. Then you can figure out how to handle the response.

```
<%= link_to "Add Friend", friendships_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :post, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

Comment: Thanks @margo I have added remote: true and added a respond to block it worked

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look:

- Move your buttons into a partial
- Render it inside a div with ID = "actions"
- Update your controller response with format js
- Add field create.js.erb which render your buttons by javascript
- Render your flashes box by javascript by the same way (if needed)

your view_file.erb

```
<div id="actions">
  <%= render "views/realtions/actions", relation: @relation, friend: @user %>
</div>
```

views/realtions/_actions.html.erb

```
<% if current_user.friend?(current_user, friend) %>
  <%= link_to "Unfriend", relation_path(relation), user: friend, method: :delete, remote: true, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure? This action cannot be undone' }, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% elsif friend != current_user %>
  <%= link_to "Add Friend", friendships_path(friend_id: friend.id), method: :post, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

views/realtions/create.js.erb

```
<%- if @friend.present? %>
  $("#actions").html("<%= j render 'views/realtions/actions', relation: @relation, friend: @friend %>")
<%- end %>
// render your flashes to DOM here!
```

controllers/relations_controller.rb

```
def create
  if params[:friend_id]
    @friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
    if Relation.where(user_id: current_user.id, friend_id: @friend.id).present?
      flash[:notice] = "Already friends"
    elsif current_user.id == params[:friend_id]
      flash[:error] = "Invalid Request"
    else
      @relation = current_user.relations.new(friend_id: params[:friend_id], subject: Constants::Subject::MAKE)
      if @relation.save
        @friend.relations.create!(friend_id: current_user.id, subject: Constants::Subject::MAKE)
        flash[:notice] = "Added as friend"
      else
        flash[:error] = "Could not add as friend"
      end
    end
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Invalid Request"
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks Nhã Huỳnh it helped me a lot